# What does GPU serialized mean?

Tags: gpu

With GPU isolation : multiple processes use the single GPU will be serialized, cause OOM easily
link
https://www.slideshare.net/mobile/Hadoop_Summit/deep-learning-on-yarn-running-distributed-tensorflow-etc-on-hadoop-cluster-v3
slide number 17

Comment: Can you give more context to your question? Is this a quote from some documentation? Can you link where you read it?

Answer (score 4):

It's saying that if you're using a single GPU, the multiple processes attempting to use the GPU will be queued up and run one at a time rather than some or all being run in parallel. If you have multiple GPUs some of the processes can be run at the same time.